# Website Create provisioning Failed in Azure. Trying to create a new website in Azure are getting error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Hi Guys anyone know what could be causing this. My database username and password is 100% correct because I can use those credentials to connect via management studio. stuck on this....

Error Number: 18456 Error Code: -2146232060 Message: Login failed for user 'scobiej@zlvnxgqm4d'.
 This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'eea2cc66-2174-4eed-8499-c1378c73f748'. Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> My database username and password is 100% correct

I guess you are trying to connect to your Azure Subscription to publish a website, not trying to connect to your database. Make sure you use you Azure Subscription credentials instead of your database login